# Regular expression in perl does not work as expected

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have a simple bash script that uses a line of perl code + regex to extract the necessary piece of string. It looks like

```
ANSWER=$(host $IPW 2>/dev/null | perl -p -e 's#^.+\s\b([a-zA-Z]{4,8}\d{1,3})(?=-\d\.).+$#\1#;'
```

It works for the most part, but produces unexpected matches from time to time. Example:

```
$ echo "Host 31.201.188.199.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)" | perl -p -e 's#^.+?\s\b([a-zA-Z]{4,8}\d{1,3})(?=-\d\.).+?(?=\.$)#\1#;'

Host 31.201.188.199.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

The string is supposed to match parts of string like "server100" (letters + digits) and return the corresponding part. Is there something I am missing or don't understand yet. (sorry for bothering)

Comment: There is no match. Try `,, server100-4.,,` Note that there is no need for `\s\b` since between space<here>letter is a word boundary. Remove one of those.

Comment: Also, there is no need for `^` as `.+` will not only force a required character, but will get the _last_ found (of what comes after).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match, so no substitution is made. The line is therefore printed as is.

If you don't want to print when there is no match, you can use `-n` instead of `-p`, plus `and print` to print the line on successful substitution:

```
echo "Host 31.201.188.199.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)" | 
    perl -n -e 's#^.+?\s\b([a-zA-Z]{4,8}\d{1,3})(?=-\d\.).+?(?=\.$)#\1# and print'
```

Comment: What's working? `\s\b([a-zA-Z]{4,8}\d{1,3})(?=-\d\.)` doesn't match anything in `Host 31.201.188.199.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)` I don't see it. Oh wait, he just doesn't want it to print.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the sample text that you show shouldn't be printed at all?

I suggest that you use a simple match instead of a substitution. I've also removed the superfluous parts of your regex pattern

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /.*\s([a-z]{4,8}\d{1,3})(?=-\d\.)/i'
```